# Running TFS Build 2015 Steps in parallel

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild

In my build definition I deploy to multiple Azure cloud services and would like to deploy in parallel, however the build definition in 2015 doesn't allow steps to be run this way.

Is there a way I can have three groups of steps (each with a Visual Studio Build and then Azure Cloud Service Deployment step) running in parallel.

This will save me huge amounts of time in our CI/CD builds allowing for faster feedback from the builds.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deploying from a build, deploy using the Release hub.

You can define multiple release environments, then use the "Deployment Conditions" option to set multiple environments to deploy at once. However, you would need one agent per environment so that the agents can run in parallel.

[image: One]

[image: TWo]

[image: Three]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are not parallel tasks in the VSTS build and release process. However, there is a uservoice item for it. Please vote for it!

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13481574-add-ability-to-run-build-steps-in-parallel